# NHibernate ordering by count of child collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have two tables, VEHICLE and PASSENGER. Vehicle can hold multiple passengers. so the PASSENGER table has a vehicleId column. I need to filter and order my view which displays vehicles by the passenger count.

VehicleEntity and PassengerEntity are used for mapping to base.

```
public class VehicleEntity
{
  public virtual long DbId {get; set;}
  public virtual string licence {get; set;}

  public virtual ISet<PassengerEntity> Passengers {get; set;}
}

public class VehicleEntityMap : ClassMap<VehicleEntity>
{
  Table("Vehicle");

  Id(x => x.DbId)

  Map(x => x.licence);
  HasMany(x => x.Passengers).KeyColumn("VehicleDbID).Inverse();
}
```

and the PassengerEntity

```
public class PassengerEntity
{
  public virtual DbId {get; set;}
  public virtual VehicleEntity Vehicle {get; set;}
}

public class PassengerEntityMap : ClassMap<PassengerEntity>
{
  Table("Passenger");

  Id(x => x.DbId)

  References(p => p.Vehicle).Column("VehicleDbId).Index("IXFK_Passenger_Vehicle");
  HasMany(x => x.Passengers).KeyColumn("VehicleDbID).Inverse();
}
```

I have managed the filter part by using the following:

```
VehicleEntity v = null;
PassengerEntity p = null;
IQueryOver<VehicleEntity , VehicleEntity > orderQuery=
            context.Session.QueryOver<VehicleEntity >(() => o);

orderQuery = orderQuery.Left.JoinAlias(() => o.Vehicles, () => v);
subQuery = QueryOver.Of<PassengerEntity>(() => p)
              .Where(() => p.Vehicle.DbId == v.DbId)
              .ToRowCountQuery();
orderFilterQuery = orderQuery.WithSubquery.WhereValue(2).Eq(sbuQuery);
```

Now I need to sort vehicles by asc/desc based on the number of passengers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same Subquery for `.OrderBy()` by using a `Projection`. (Btw., if you filter the records like you do in your example, then sorting by number of passengers won't do much, since you only get records with the same number of passengers.)

```
orderQuery.OrderBy(Projections.SubQuery(subQuery)).Asc;
```

The resulting SQL will look something like:

```
ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM PASSENGERS this_0_ WHERE this_0_.DBID = this_.DBID) asc
```